# approve a request even when the approval email link has been lost

Tags: sharepoint-server, approval-process

I have created a workflow which runs when a form request has been submitted. 
 Currently, the approval manager will receive a notification email with a link to the approval page.

However, as some managers seems to be; they tend to delete the emails and the approval process remains pending.

> is there an option to add a button or a link that takes you
>   directly to the approval page?!

[image]

This where the approval manager sees the pending requests. 
At minute, if the email has been lost > there is no (simple) way of approving it.

**What I also have tried out:**

Since it is a Document Library > I also tried the **Content Approval** 
`Require content approval for submitted items? > YES`

but the approval process does not work! 
For some reason, it does not interact with the WF at all.

Any suggestions?



 PS: The CapEx Approval is the actual workflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Figured out that this can be achieved via 2 options:

1. add the Approval process column to the view
2. add the Nintex workflow approval tasks web part

[image]
Whereby the second option is a great feature :) 
it lists all your outstanding / pending approvals.